# Receiving SOCKET_ERROR when using WinSock

Tags: c++, mfc

I have looked around the forum and googled for a few hours, but couldn't find the exact solution. If you could give me some information about what's wrong with this code, I would be very grateful. I've tried a lot of things, but can't seem to get anything working. A lot of the code is taken from Microsoft's article: [Complete WinSock client code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx).

Code in C++:

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif


#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main() {
WSADATA wsaData;

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"
SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
    *ptr = NULL,
    hints;
char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int iResult;
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", NULL, &hints, &result);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
        ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Send an initial buffer
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

// shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Receive until the peer closes the connection
do {

    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0)
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
    else if (iResult == 0)
        printf("Connection closed\n");
    else
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

} while (iResult > 0);

// cleanup
closesocket(ConnectSocket);
WSACleanup();
getchar();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: So at which line are you getting `SOCKET_ERROR`? Have you tried calling `WSAGetLastError` to retrieve error code?

Comment: Got anything more specific than that it doesn't work? Like, for example, the results of that `WSAGetLastError()` call ? Your question should include the *exact* output. I see you're at least *getting* that error result, but do you mind sharing it with the rest of us?

Comment: I apologize. iResult == SOCKET_ERROR on the line beneath "// Connect to server.". Let me try.

Comment: Received 10049 (WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL). Description (on Microsoft's pages) says there could be a lot of reasons. Not valid on the local computer, for instance, but I don't know why that is.

Comment: Why did I get downvoted? Did I do something wrong? I tried my best to ask a question in the kindest of ways, but it's not always as easy to exactly what information to supply at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to specify the TCP port number on which you want to connect. It's the second argument to [`getaddrinfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx).

For example like this:

```
  iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "80", &hints, &result);
```

Comment: Now I got connection refused instead (10061). I don't know why that is. Firewall?

Comment: You need to have some server process running that listens on the specified port.

Comment: I managed to connect to a server, and bytes where received correctly. Thank you so much for your help!